# decltype not deducing pointer from function causing wrong trait class to be called

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

class person{
public:
    person(){
        cout << "default ctor\n";
    };
    person(string const & name) : name(name){
        cout << "in name ctor\n";
    }
    person(person const & other) : name(other.name){
        cout << "copy ctor\n";
    }
    person& operator = (person other){
        cout << "copy assign oper\n";
        std::swap(name,other.name);
        return *this;
    }
    person(person&& other) : name(std::move(other.name)){
        cout << "Move ctor\n";
    }
    person& operator = (person && other){
        name = std::move(other.name);
        cout << "Move assign operator\n";
        return *this;
    }
    void print() const{
        cout << name << endl;
    }
private:
    string name;
};

template<class T>
class get_unwrapped{
public:
    T& get(T& t){
        return t;
    }
};


template<class T>
class get_unwrapped<T*>{
public:
    T& get(T* t){
        return *t;
    }
};

template<class T>
class get_unwrapped<shared_ptr<T>>{
public:
    T& get(shared_ptr<T>& t){
        return *t;
    }
};

template<class T>
void print_all(T&& elements){    
    for(auto it = std::begin(elements); it != std::end(elements); ++it){
        get_unwrapped<decltype(*it)> unwrapper;
        auto &result = unwrapper.get(*it);
        result.print();
    }
}


int main()
{

    vector<person*> v;

    v.reserve(3);
    v.push_back(new person("Blair"));
    v.push_back(new person("Esther"));

    print_all(v);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What about posting some actual error messages? Explaining what this code is supposed to do? Reducing the code to the minimum that reproduces your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`operator*` of an iterator returns a reference type, so the pointer specialization is not a match.

Your code works if you say this:

```
get_unwrapped< typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*it)>::type > unwrapper;
```

You can try it:

```
std::cout << std::is_same< decltype(*it), person*&>::value;
```

prints `1`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Perfect... What are your thoughts on how the code is laid out btw?

Comment: As in to have one generic method to handle vector<int>. vector<int*>, vector<shared<int>>

Comment: What the other answer suggests looks good, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply function templates?

```
template<class T>
T& get_unwrapped(T& t){
  return t;
}

template<class T>
T& get_unwrapped(T* t){
  return *t;
}

template<class T>
T& get_unwrapped(shared_ptr<T>& t){
  return *t;
}

// ...
auto &result = get_unwrapped(*it);
result.print();
```